# Python: abstract model and strings

Tags: python, model, abstract, pyomo

I have an abstract model program that only manipulates values. I wonder if its possible to do the same with strings. Below is part of my code that uses numbers. Does someone know how to use string and how is that syntax?

This is model program:

```
model        = AbstractModel()
model.I      = Set(ordered=True) #Set of inputs
model.J      = Set(ordered=True) #Set of outputs
model.K      = Set(ordered=True) #Set of DMUs
model.D      = Set(ordered=True)

model.x      = Param(model.K,model.I, within=NonNegativeReals) #Input weights
model.y      = Param(model.K,model.J, within=Reals) #Output weights
model.xp     = Param(model.I, within=NonNegativeReals, mutable=True) #Input weights for DMU p
model.yp     = Param(model.J, within=Reals, mutable=True) #Output weights for DMU p
...
```

This is where i need to compare with string, getting abstract model value instead of 'DMU':

```
def cost_rule(model):
    return (sum(model.z[k] for k in model.K if k != 'DMU') + 1)
```

Constraint 3 as example:

```
def constraint2_rule(model):
    return sum(model.xp[i]*model.u[i] for i in model.I) == 1
```

This is the DATA.dat file:

```
set I := opex;
set I := opex;
set J := rsub rdist ralta cons mpond perdasNT ensup;
set K := D01 D02 D03...;

param x: 
opex :=
D01  270955.14715
D02  375627.795556
D03  480112.16082
...
param y :
  rsub rdist ralta cons mpond perdasNT ensup :=
D01  0  63723.23554  1971.313333  1239688  3673950.787  -251586.2972  -8024138.997
D02  0  41606.21633  285.4386667  755385.6667  2220492.184  -2041869.829  -25019876.08
...
param     xp := 
 opex     270955.14715;

param       yp:= 
 rsub       0.0
 rdist      63723.23554
 ralta      1971.313333
 cons        1239688
 mpond      3673950.787
 perdasNT  -251586.2972
 ensup     -8024138.997;
```

Comment: yes, nice question: pyomo.environ

Comment: Is there an error message that you're receiving? I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: No, the program is running correctly. There is no error at all.
I'm just asking how to use string on the abstract model instead of numbers